# Cannot get C# Task exection flow to work properly

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I've got an activity that I need to run on a background thread in a C#/XAML app, so I'm doing this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ImportFile());
```

I'm returning the Task value to another bit of code that then needs to take action *after* the thread-based work has completed. The code looks like this:

```
Action<Task> finalise = async delegate { await FinishImport(dbList); };
dbList.ImportFileAsync().ContinueWith(finalise);
```

When I run the code, however, debugging statements in `FinishImport` are being executed before the background thread has finished.

What am I misunderstanding here? I thought the whole point of `ContinueWith` was that it would execute the continuation code after the target task completes.

Comment: Could you include a short, but complete sample code that demonstrates this issue? Otherwise, answering this question would require a lot of guessing.

Comment: @PhilipColmer: Did you get the `Task.Factory.StartNew` idea from a particular source? Wondering why you have that code...

Comment: The reason for Task.Factory.StartNew was because I had originally tried Task.Run and was hitting the same problem of the continuation code not actually waiting. Also, I need ImportFile to be a bit "fire and forget" in that if the app gets suspended and then restarted, I need the restart to be able to start ImportFile again and my head was exploding a bit with the contorted thoughts of execution flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Task.Run` rather than `Task.Factory.StartNew` in `async` code. `Task.Run` understands `async` methods while `StartNew` will return a `Task` representing only the beginning of that `async` method.

As a side note, it's usually best to not have `Task.Run` hidden inside a library method.

Also, it's far easier to use `await` than `ContinueWith`. And `async` methods should end with "Async".

So, applying these guidelines makes your code look like:

```
await Task.Run(() => dbList.ImportFileAsync());
await FinishImportAsync(dbList);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this hasn't worked. The execution sequence I'm seeing is:

1. Debug statement just before these two await's.

2. Debug statement from "ImportFileAsync" confirming the start of the code execution.

3. Debug statements from "FinishImportAsync".

4. More debug statements from "ImportFileAsync" confirming that the task is still running!

This is the brick wall that I've been hitting, which is why I tried using Task.Factory.StartNew instead of Task.Run (which I had previously tried). Neither await nor ContinueWith are actually waiting for the background task to finish.

Comment: What is most likely happening is that `ImportFileAsync` has a bug where it is returning while there is other work still going on. Try asking a new question, posting a minimal reproduction of the problem.

Comment: I think I've found the cause. ImportFileAsync needed to be async because of calls to GetFileAsync and OpenReadAsync. That was messing up the execution flow. I've now restructured the code so that the Task.Run is done within ImportFileAsync on the main loop rather than the whole of the code. I now just go "await dbList.ImportFileAsync();" and that has fixed it. I figured this out while I was trying to edit the original question :-)

Answer (score 0):

what `ImportFileAsync()` does?

`finalise` will run after the thread of `ImportFileAsync()` will end

if
     `ImportFileAsync(){ Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ImportFile());}`

then `ImportFileAsync` will call a new thread for `ImportFile()` and then exit it won't wait for `ImportFile()`
to finish

you wanna do

`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dbList.ImportFile()).ContinueWith(finalise);`

Comment: “after the thread will end” That's not really right. When execution of a `Task` completes, it doesn't end any `Thread`s, the `Thread` stays in the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @svick, would saying go out of scope is better? the task is completed and the thread returns to the threadpool. practicly speaking is the same..

Comment: That wouldn't be better, because scope doesn't have anything to do with this